# Как дублировать положение объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

У меня есть 2 объекта один статичный другой подвижный. Нужно чтобы статичный объект повторял положение подвижного. (Без задержек) Как это зделать? C# Unity3d

Comment: Можете как-то подробнее описать проблему?

Comment: Как мне написать код, чтобы объект повторял положение другого объекта? C#

Comment: У меня есть голова и тело. нужно чтобы тело двигалось за головой.

Comment: в иерархии объектов закинь голову в тело или наоборот, а лучше сделать отдельный бъект в котором будет и голова и тело и *****

Comment: у меня голова вращается

Comment: а тело не должно

Answer (score 1):

кода не нужно.
Должна быть иерархия:

Пустой обьект

- Подобьект1 - обьект за которым повторять движение
- Подобьект2 - повторяющий движение

если двигать пустой обьект - будут двигатся оба обьекта

если нужно поворачивать только Подобьект1 - поворачивай только его

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116213/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew----).

Answer (score 0):

Движение и вращение осуществляются из отдельного скрипта, типа PlayerMovement.
Иерархия выглядит так:

- Пустой объект (Компоненты: transform, PlayerMovement, BoxCollider, Rigidbody)

  - Голова игрока (Компоненты: графические, типа MeshFilter, MeshRenderer...)
  - Туловище игрока (Компоненты также графические)

В скрипте PlayerMovement при необходимости передвижения игрока вы двигаете ***ПУСТОЙ ОБЪЕКТ*** (под 1-й точкой). К нему вы можете обращаться через переменную типа GameObject, либо не обращаться вообще, так как скрипт висит на самом этом обхекте:

```
player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(...);
или
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(...);
```

Для поворота головы вы обращаетесь к САМОЙ голове. Через опять же публичную переменную (или SerializeField), или через GetChild (хуже).

```
Head.transform.Rotate(...)
или
transform.GetChild(0).Rotate(...)
```

Если у вас остались еще вопросы по поводу иерархии, советую добавить скриншот иерархии в вопрос.